# How to figure out which patients appeared under both IDs in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a list of patient `IDs`, but they go by two different IDs(ID1 and ID2). How do I figure out which patients on the `list` appeared under both IDs?

```
ID1 ID2
 11  12
 13  14
 15  16
 17  18
 19  20
 21  22
```

I have a list

```
list=c(11,13,14,15,16,18,18,19,20)
```

I need to see which patients appeared under both IDs, by ID1, such that I would get

```
>13,15,19
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the logic used for comparison

Comment: yeah, so on the list, there is 11, because its corresponding ID2 "12" didn't appear in the list, so 11 would not appear in the output. There is also 13. Both ID1 and ID2(13,14) appeared in the list, so 13 would appear in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could loop over the dataset with `lapply`, check whether the elements are `%in%` the 'list' object (not recommended to name objects with function names), `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `&` (it implies TRUE only if both columns have the value in the 'list').  Use the logical index to subset the values of "ID1"

```
df1$ID1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1, `%in%`, list))]
#[1] 13 15 19
```

---

Or another option is `filter` with `across` from `dplyr`.  It will `filter` only those rows having both column values are present and then `pull` the 'ID1' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(across(everything(), ~ . %in% list)) %>% 
   pull(ID1)
#[1] 13 15 19
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID1 = c(11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L), ID2 = c(12L, 
 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `match` + `complete.cases`

```
> df$ID1[complete.cases(sapply(df, match, table = lst))]
[1] 13 15 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` you could do :

```
df$ID1[rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, list)) == ncol(df)]
#[1] 13 15 19
```